# How not to block UI while downloading data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have question regarding DispatchQueue. In one of my view controllers, I do need to download an image from web and display it on a UIImageView. While the app downloading the image, I am trying not to block the UI using DispatchQueue. The below code does not seem to work. Can anyone explain why? and how to do this properly?

```
let store_id = self.store!._id

DispatchQueue.global().async {
let imageUrl = URL(string: "www.image.com")
self.storeImageData = imageUrl != nil ? try? Data(contentsOf:imageUrl!) : nil

    if self.storeImageData != nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.topBackgroundImageView.image = UIImage(data:self.storeImageData!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `try? Data(contentsOf:imageUrl!)`  is downloading your data synchronously, instead you should download your contents asynchronously  using either `URLSession` or `Alamofire`

Comment: @Lamar But I am downloading data inside async block. Does that still blocking UI?

Comment: yes it is, I've added in answer

Comment: @Lamar, since the code is in global queue, irrespective of it being synchronous, should it affect the main queue?

Comment: @eChung00 I don't think the above code should block UI. It works fine at my end. Check out if any other thing is making your UI Blocked

Comment: Try using Activity Indicator to block the UI till the data loaded and remove the activity indicator once done.

Answer (score 0):

I would not [recommend](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init) your way of downloading over the network, use either `URLSession` or `Alamofire`. Here is some code you can follow:

```
func downloadImageFrom(urlString:String, completion:@escaping(Data?)->()) {
    guard let url = URL(string:urlString) else { return }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, err) in
        if err != nil {
            // handle error if any
        }
        // you should check the reponse status
        // if data is a json object/dictionary so decode it
        // if data is regular data then pass it to your callback
        completion(data)
    }.resume()
}

func doWork() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return } // to avoid reference cycle
        strongSelf.downloadImageFrom(urlString: "http://www.image.com", completion: { (data) in
            if let _data = data {
                // now you have the data
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // display your imageView with the data
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You commented above " `try? Data(contentsOf:imageUrl!)` is downloading your data synchronously, instead you should download your contents asynchronously using either URLSession or Alamofire"

I believe the code is written is global queue with async, then how does it do asynchronously.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari apple docs suggest that we don't do that, I've added to reference

Comment: Apple doc suggest not to do that on main queue. But as per the question, the OP is already grabbing a default qoS background thread using `DispatchQueue.global().async` and I believe that is good to go.

Comment: The code `DispatchQueue.global().async {}` grabs a background thread with qos' default value as `DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default`

Comment: you don't know how big is the file that the OP is downloading so just the code that the OP implemented should be avoided, I would use that code if the file was already downloaded and the file size is very small

Comment: I am not saying it is a good way or he should or shouldn't do that. I am just asking how the code written inside `DispatchQueue.global().async {}` is synchronous. Because I downloaded a 40 mb image file using the same code and UI never blocked.

Comment: but you need to remember that dispatch queue can execute both synchronous and asynchronous code

Comment: Exactly it does, but as per the code written, it should not block the UI. I think  it will always do in background.

Comment: If he had written `.sync` then it might be the problem for UI block. But here in the question itself, we get a background thread and all the initialization of contents are done in background

Comment: I do get what you are saying but i would not recommend it

Comment: Thats your suggestion and I also know that its not a good way. Again my question is not which is good or bad. My question is still how `DispatchQueue.global().async {}` is synchronous as mentioned by you. You mentioned that `Data(contentsOf:imageUrl!)` is synchronous and its true. But how if it is written in `DispatchQueue.global().async {}` and is still blocking the UI. I am not making any assumptions, I tested it before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Hope will helpful to you download an image from web and display it on a UIImageView.

SDWebImage does very aggressive caching by default. It ignores all kind of caching control header returned by the HTTP server and cache the returned images with no time restriction. It implies your images URLs are static URLs pointing to images that never change. If the pointed image happen to change, some parts of the URL should change accordingly.

```
import SDWebImage

imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://www.image.com/image.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))

// Or using this code
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.image.com/image.jpg"]
         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar-placeholder.png"]
                  options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

**Add a progress indicator**

```
imageView.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
imageView.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.Gray)
```